# Should I install a wall before or after hardwood floor installation?

Tags: walls, flooring, floor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Frame or floor planks first?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2680/frame-or-floor-planks-first)

I am building a small wall between two rooms. The existing flooring was carpet, which I have removed. I plan to install a floating floor (the floor is concrete, on the 4th floor). My question is should I install the channel for the wall directly on the concrete and then build the wall and install the floor around it, or install the flooring first and then build the wall on top?

If it makes a difference, the wall will be small, only about 16"x5"x96"

Comment: @NiallC. I think my question is different, as I'm asking about a floating floor and not a traditional wood floor. Though it looks as though the answer is similar none-the-less.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a true floating floor like Pergo or a similar product I would suspect that the wall would need to be done first.If you build the wall on top of the flooring it will no longer float and buckling will occur as the flooring expands and contracts.This is why they recomend spacing between the flooring and fixed points like walls,cabinets etc.

Comment: This was my thought too, but I wanted to make sure.